# Find $\beta _{1}, \beta _{2}, \beta _{3}, \beta _{4} \in \mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra

> In the linear space $\mathbb R^{2,2}$ there are matrices $A_{1}={\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}}$, $A_{2}={\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}}$, $A_{3}={\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}}$, $A_{4}={\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}}$. 
>  (a)Prove that $(A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}, A_{4})$ is a basis of the space $\mathbb R^{2,2}$. 
>  (b) $g_{1}^{*}, g_{2}^{*}, g_{3}^{*}, g_{4}^{*} \in (\mathbb R^{2,2})^{*}$ is a dual basis from basis $(A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}, A_{4})$. 
>  Functional $f^{*} \in  (\mathbb R^{2,2})^{*}$ is given by the formula: $f^{*}({\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}})=a_{11} + a_{12} + a_{21} + a_{22}$. 
> Find $\beta _{1}, \beta _{2}, \beta _{3}, \beta _{4} \in \mathbb R$ such that $f^{*}=\beta _{1} g_{1}^{*}+\beta _{2} g_{2}^{*}+\beta _{3} g_{3}^{*}+\beta _{4} g_{4}^{*}$.

I think (a) is easy and I know how to do it. 
 Hovewer in (b) I have my sollution but I think it is not good answer, so I need an opinion to my approach:
 1) I find a dual basis from basis $(A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}, A_{4})$: $${\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}}=\alpha_{1} A_{1}+\alpha_{2} A_{2}+\alpha_{3} A_{3}+\alpha_{4} A_{4}$$ 
 2) Then I have $$\alpha_{1}=g_{1}^{*}, \alpha_{2}=g_{2}^{*}, \alpha_{3}=g_{3}^{*}, \alpha_{4}=g_{4}^{*}$$ 

3) $f^{*}=\beta _{1} g_{1}^{*}+\beta _{2} g_{2}^{*}+\beta _{3} g_{3}^{*}+\beta _{4} g_{4}^{*}$ so I substitute the early calculated values.